# Invision Community 4 class 'IPS\Content\Search\Mysql\Index' not found

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, invision-power-board

i want to install IPBoard 4.4.9, but every time i had this error. I downgraded MySQL to 5.7, but also dont work, does somebody can help me?

[image]